# Defining a variable of a yet undefined enumeration type

Tags: c, enums

If speaking of structures and unions, I can define a variable of one of these types out of a function scope when the types themselves have only been declared and are to be defined later:

```
struct my_struct;
struct my_struct variable;
struct my_struct { int field_1; };
```

I used `clang` and `gcc` compilers, and in the both cases the programmes compiled warninglessly.

However, if I try this out with an enumeration type, it only works with `clang`:

```
enum my_enum;
enum my_enum variable;
enum my_enum {CONST};
```

Whilst `gcc` throws an error *storage size of 'variable' isn't known*.

I wonder, why is it like that? Is there something special about enumeration types in C?

Comment: MSVC will compile that. But I would not use a keyword, even if it is in upper case.

Comment: *Whilst gcc throws an error storage size of 'variable' isn't known.* That's not 100% accurate, gcc 10.1, 10.2 and trunk compile the code.

Comment: @anastaciu mine is 8.1

Comment: @Kaiyakha, yes, until 9.3 it doesn't compile with the error you mentioned.

Comment: @anastaciu well it will not compile `enum` only, and I'm curious if there is something behind the scenes about this keyword

Comment: @Kaiyakha, well there is the elephant in the room, forward declaring enums is not C standard compliant, so the first 2 are a problem.

Comment: @anastaciu the first two what?

Comment: `enum my_enum;` and `enum my_enum variable;` are forward declarations.

Comment: @anastaciu ah you meant two lines of code :) didn't get it first

Comment: @Kaiyakha, yes, what I don't get is why `gcc` started to allow it recently, maybe some extension.

Comment: @Kaiyakha the fact of the matter is that neither declaration is valid, variables can only have 1 name, the forward declarations are making the compiler accept the constructs when they should be rejected, if you remove them it behave as expected https://godbolt.org/z/obWenj

Comment: @anastaciu the two pieces of code are from different programmes, if this is what you mean

Comment: @Kaiyakha, what I mean is that for the best of my knowledge both `enum my_enum variable;` and `struct my_struct variable;` are illegal declarations.

Comment: @anastaciu they are probably not recommended by the convention, but I'm only worried about actual mechanisms, like will I be able to replace my car's wheels with a simple screwdriver. Sounds weird, but some people are so curious sometimes they would even push their fingers into a socket :)

Comment: @Kaiyakha, yes, curiosity is a great quality in my book, you did uncover a strange behavior in the compilers so that's a plus.